# css transition border is contained except for fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css, border, css-transitions

For learning purposes, I have been playing with different css transition effects. I cannot, however, figure this bit out.

**A simple setup:** top nav with a toggle icon to display a sidebar `<aside>`. Sidebar items are wrapped in a `<div id='swap'>`. One of the sidebar items needs to be at the bottom and I have set its position to fixed. Here is the jquery:

```
(function() {
  $(".toggle-wrap").on("click", function() {
    $("i").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
    $("main").toggleClass("main push");
    $("aside").animate({ width: "toggle" }, 200);
    $("#swap").toggleClass("hidden shown");
  });
})();
```

The click swiftly moves the main content to the right and makes the `<aside>` itself visible ***and*** then makes the sidebar items visible via a transition (`cubic-bezier(0.32, 1.25, 0.375, 1.15)`)

**The trouble:** the cubic-bezier makes a "playful" entrance but it overflows only for the fixed item at the bottom and the `overflow:hidden` does not seem to have any effect. After the transition, it is perfectly in place. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

**My question:** How can I contain the border/prevent this overflow with the fixed position?

[I have made a codepen to have the entire code available](https://codepen.io/persianphilosopher/pen/LQGevW?editors=0100).

Comment: change `fixed` with `absolute` and the issue will be fixed :)

Comment: Ugh. Can't believe I spent so much time trying all kinds of tweaks but not that one...Thank you.

Comment: If you make that an answer, by the way, I would gladly accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `position:fixed` the element will be positioned relative to the viewport and thus the overflow of its parent container won't work.

To fix this simply switch to `position:absolute` and your element will be positioned relative **to the nearest positioned ancestor** and in your case it's the `aside` element and the `overflow:hidden` of this element will hide your overflowing border.

---

**And why both values of position give the same result?**

Simply because in your case, you applied only `bottom:0` and since your `aside` is taking full height of the screen, `bottom:0` will refer to same position which is the bottom of the screen. You may adjust slightly the height of `aside` and you will notice the difference between `fixed` and `absolute` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Very helpful!

Comment: @Farhang i also added another part so you understand why in your case both behave the same as they are different

Answer (score 1):

I used flexboxes and added a few wrapper classes. Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
(function() {
  $(".toggle-wrap").on("click", function() {
    $("i").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
    $(".aside").animate({
      width: "toggle"
    }, 200);
    $(".lower").toggleClass("hidden shown");
    $(".upper").toggleClass("hidden shown");
  });
})();
```

```css
html,
body,
.site-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  font: normal 1em "Arial";
  background: #212121;
  color: #fff;
}

.site-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  color: #000;
}

.toggle-wrap {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*disable selection*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.aside {
  background: #383838;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.aside-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30vw;
}

.upper,
.lower {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: all 1950ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 1.25, 0.375, 1.15);
  transition-delay: 300ms;
  width: 30vw;
}

.upper {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.lower {
  border-top: 2px solid yellow;
}

a {
  padding: 12px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
}

.hidden {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.shown {
  transition: all 1950ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 1.25, 0.375, 1.15);
  transition-delay: 300ms;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.main {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="toggle-wrap">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <aside class="aside">
      <div class="aside-content">
        <div class="upper hidden">
          <a href="#">BRAND</a>
          <a href="#">another item</a>
        </div>
        <div class="lower hidden">
          <a href="#">Menu</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <main class='main'>
      CONTENT
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Added border to top of `.upper`