# Scrollbar removing tooltip in HTML

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone knows why adding overflow-y:scroll into my container CSS removes the tooltip triangle (at the very bottom of the container). This is a working example:

```css
#container{
background-color:rgb(66, 66, 66);
width:500x;
height: 300px;
position:relative;


}

#container::after{
 content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* At the bottom of the tooltip */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px; /*margin-left needs to be the same as border width */
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(66, 66, 66) transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div  id="container">
  
</div>
```

```css
#container{
background-color:rgb(66, 66, 66);
width:500px;
height: 300px;
position:relative;
overflow-y:scroll;

}

#container::after{
 content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; /* At the bottom of the tooltip */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px; /*margin-left needs to be the same as border width */
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(66, 66, 66) transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">



</div>
```

The only difference between these two code snippets is the "overflow-y:scroll" property inside `#container` . If anyone can explain why this happens, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: simply because your element is overflowing

Comment: top:100% is not bottom:0 ... try them both and you will see the difference, top:100% make the element outside. Check dev tools and you will see this

Comment: I tried bottom:0. But my understanding is that because the tooltip is absolutely positioned, it should not have any effect on the layout/spacing of its parent container. So it is kind of puzzling why adding a scrollbar would cause it to be removed

Comment: it's always linked to its parent because it's positioned relatively to him .. try position:fixed and you won't have this issue. or remove relative from container and see the difference

Comment: check this question where we had to deal with a similar case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591336/css-transition-border-is-contained-except-for-fixed-div/48591647#48591647

Comment: position fixed does not work. After inspecting element, it appears that the tooltip is outside of the container but it is simply not visible

Comment: use position fixed and also change top property to see it :) i didn't meant that position:fixed with solve the issue but to show you that your element will be visible because with position fixed it will positioned relative to viewport and overflow will no more affect it

Comment: same thing when you remove position:relative from its parent ... the element will be positioned relative to first positioned ancestor and in this case it's simply the viewport and thus the overflow won't affect him too

Comment: and since it's actually positioned relative to this container, the overflow will affect him and it will be non visibile because it's overflowing the container (overflow:hidden will also have the same effect)

Comment: check this fiddle and see how element behave and you will understand : https://jsfiddle.net/v479ve8g/1/

Comment: even after removing positon relative from the parent and applying position fixed on the tooltip, it is still outside of the container and invisible

Comment: because you have top:100% :) check my fiddle and you will understand. You have two issue: top:100% will always make your element outside it's conainer so in the first case it's hidden by overflow and with fixed position it's hidden because out of the screen